# Use PLY to match a normal string

Tags: python-2.7, lex, lexer, ply

I am writing a parser by using [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). The question is similar to this one [How to write a regular expression to match a string literal where the escape is a doubling of the quote character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143235/how-to-write-a-regular-expression-to-match-a-string-literal-where-the-escape-is). However, I use double-quote to open and close a string. For example:

> "I do not know what \"A\" is"

I define the normal string lexer as:

```
t_NORMSTRING = r'"([^"\n]|(\\"))*"$'
```

and I have another lexer for a variable:

```
def t_VAR(t):
   r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
```

The problem is my lexer doesn't recognize "I do not know what \"A\" is" as a NORMSTRING token. It returns the error

```
Illegal character '"' at 1
Syntax error at 'LexToken(VAR,'do',10,210)'
```

Please let me know why it is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having explored this issue with a little PLY program, I think your issue is related to the differences between [handling raw and non-raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688511/raw-input-if-statements-python) in the data handling, and not with the PLY parsing and lexical matching itself. (Just as a side note, there are minor differences between [python V2 and python v3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) in this area of string handling. I have restricted my code to python v2).

You only get the error you are seeing if you use a non-raw string or use `input` instead of `raw_input`. This is shown from my example code and results below:

> Commands:
>
> ```
> $ python --version
> Python 2.7.5
> $ python string.py
> ```

```
import sys

if ".." not in sys.path: sys.path.insert(0,"..")
import ply.lex as lex
tokens = (
    'NORMSTRING',
    'VAR'
)

def t_NORMSTRING(t):
     r'"([^"\n]|(\\"))*"$'
     print "String: '%s'" % t.value

def t_VAR(t):
   r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'

t_ignore = ' \t\r\n'

def t_error(t):
    print "Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0]
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

data = r'"I do not know what \"A\" is"'

print "Data: '%s'" % data

lexer.input(data)

while True:
   tok = lexer.token()
   if not tok: break
   print tok
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Data: '"I do not know what \"A\" is"'
> String: '"I do not know what \"A\" is"'
> ```

```
data = '"I do not know what \"A\" is"'

print "Data: '%s'" % data

lexer.input(data)

while True:
   tok = lexer.token()
   if not tok: break
   print tok
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Data: '"I do not know what "A" is"'
> Illegal character '"'
> Illegal character '"'
> String: '" is"'
> ```

```
lexer.input(raw_input("Please type your line: "));

while True:
   tok = lexer.token()
   if not tok: break
   print tok
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Please type your line: "I do not know what \"A\" is"
> String: '"I do not know what \"A\" is"'
> ```

```
lexer.input(input("Please type your line: "));

while True:
   tok = lexer.token()
   if not tok: break
   print tok
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Please type your line: "I do not know what \"A\" is"
> Illegal character '"'
> Illegal character '"'
> ```

As a final note, You probably do not need the string anchor `$` in your regular expression.